# "Can not find file" makefile error

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile a C++ program using make. I want it to read the source files from the src folder. Place the object files in the build folder, and put the exe in the bin folder.

I get the following error

> /bin/wavfiletool.exe -g -O2  process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,
>   /bin/wavfiletool.exe -g -O2, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

UPDATE: The problem was I put g++ in for my compiler var instead of &(CC)...woops.

But now it says g++: fatal error: no input files
I am running make using a batch file that sets the environment variables.

```
SET PATH=C:\Make\GnuWin32\bin;C:\MinGW\bin
make %1
```

My makefile is as follows.

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -g -O2
BIN_DIR := /bin
BUILD_DIR := /build
SRC_DIR := /src
TARGET := wavfiletool.exe
SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(G++) $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the `$(G++)` variable anywhere so the recipe line for the `$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET)` target is trying to run `$@` instead of the compiler.

Also you are missing `-o` on that compilation line so were `$(G++)` set to `g++` correctly you would end up running:

```
g++ /bin/wavfiletool.exe -g -O2 $(OBJECTS)
```

which likely isn't what you want.

*That* being said you probably don't want to be writing **directly** into `/bin` either. Did you mean `./bin` for a `bin` directory in the local directory?

Comment: ./bin? Is that linux. I am on windows. I am writing into the bin directory of my project. Within the project main folder I have bin , build , src.

Comment: Right. Windows. Then just leave off the `/` entirely I believe. Though `.\bin` should also work in `cmd.exe`/etc. I believe.