# makefile "no such file or directory"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile a C++ program using make. After reading quite a few tutorials, I have come upon the following make file.

It reads source files from src directory, puts objects in the build directory, and puts the exe in the bin directory.

When I try running the following makefile, I get the subsequent error.

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -g -O2
BIN_DIR := /bin
BUILD_DIR := /build
SRC_DIR := /src
TARGET := wavfiletool.exe
SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

> ++ /bin/wavfiletool.exe -g -O2  g++: error: /bin/wavfiletool.exe: No such file or directory g++: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. make: *** [/bin/wavfiletool.exe] Error 1 [Finished in 0.1s
>   with exit code 2]

UPDATE:

I have edited the makefile. One typo in the previous version was that I have .c when I am using .cpp and c++. I am now getting a different error.

UPDATED MAKEFILE

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -g -O2
BIN_DIR := bin
BUILD_DIR := build
SRC_DIR := src
TARGET := wavfiletool.exe
SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ 

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

new error

```
makefile:13: target `src/WavFile.cpp' doesn't match the target pattern
makefile:13: target `src/WavFileTool.cpp' doesn't match the target pattern
g++ src/WavFile.cpp src/WavFileTool.cpp -g -O2  -o bin/wavfiletool.exe
```

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33090003/258523) on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33089932/258523) covers these issues. I covered three issues with your makefile. The incorrect variable was just one of them. Also, if my answer was correct you should accept it (and not edit your question to indicate that you found the solution).

Comment: I looked over your answer to the other error, but this error persists, even with the -o properly added.

Comment: Update the post and add the new makefile (with the slash fix and the `-o` fix) and show us the new error output. It is extremely unlikely to be the same error. Please include the *entire* output from running `make` **including** the invocation of `make` itself and the `g++` command that fails. (And use code formatting not quote formatting so SO doesn't mangle the newlines please.)

Comment: There is a strange `:` in the middle of the OBJECTS rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless all of your directories (i.e., BIN_DIR, SRC_DIR) are in the root directory (/) then that is why you're getting the error. You either want to remove the initial slash or you can use an environment variable prefix like `SRC_DIR = $(MY_PROJECT_BASE_DIRECTORY)/src`.

Comment: I have removed the '/' character. It still gives the same error.